# display Two activity on Same screen

Tags: android

I am working on Android 3.0 where I need to divide screen on two parts where one part should Attached under activity A and second with Actvity B, how it would possible? I tried it using fragment but fragment is attached with one activity. but my challenge is with two activtiy.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity() , A.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Use Fragments for this purpose. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: do you mind explaining why using fragments doesn't satisfy your requirement

Comment: You can attach multiple fragments to an activity.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. For that purpose you need to use [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), that was what it was designed for. The screen estate on mobile devices is already limited, hence, the design choice not to support multiple activities sharing the screen.

If you think you require two activities, I would suggest you rethink your design. If you need functionality in addition to what one Activity can offer, I suggest using a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). More details on why you made this design choice would have been helpful.